# Qt OpenGL FrameBufferObject texture accessed from different threads

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a qt app that uses a QOpenGLWidget. This has a thread that is subclassed from QThread and it's job is to take decoded video frames and mix them together based on their alpha values. This is done with a secondary context that was created on the main thread and passed into the QThread with QThread::moveToThread. Also the QOpenGLWidget context and secondary context are shared and i checked that they are actaully sharing. It uses an QOffscreenSurface (that was also created in the main thread) and a QOpenGLFrameBufferObject that is drawn in the secondary thread. I can convert that framebuffer object to an image and save it and it's what I would expect. I then call:

```
    m_context->functions()->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 12);
    m_context->functions()->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fbo->texture());
```

This is in hopes that i can just call

```
    m_program->setUniformValue("onscreenTexture", 12);
```

in my main Gui thread Draw function and that texture will just be accessible. This works when i recreate it all on the main GUI and draw to the fbo then bind the fbo texture then draw with a different shader the sampler values at that texture slot. I know there are a lot of people that are just going to blindly comment about posting code but it's very verbose and I'm hoping maybe someone can spot something obvious that I'm missing. It seems like I should be able to:

1. Create a second context and an offscreen surface on the main thread
2. Pass those to a secondary thread and process offscreen drawing onto an FBO
3. Bind that FBO texture to a specified texture slot
4. Draw whats in that texture slot using a shader on the main thread that's tied to that slot that the FBO was bound to.

But the million dollar question is why can't I get that FBO texture data in the main thread. I can get the FBO texture data in the secondary thread as an image and I can get the FBO texture data on the main thread by binding it and using it in with a second shader but I just can't seem to get it all working over separate threads.
These are the main thread functions and shader that draw to the FBO and this works. The FBO will put out a correct image.

```
void VideoPanel::RunTextureThread()
{
    m_terminateThread = false;
    if (m_textureThread.get() && m_textureThread->isRunning())
        return;

    m_context->moveToThread(m_textureThread.get());
    m_textureThread->start();
}

void TextureThread::run()
{
    Initialize();

    while (!QThread::currentThread()->isInterruptionRequested())
    {
        while (!m_mutex->try_lock());
        m_context->makeCurrent(m_surface);

        if (m_gObj->LoadNextTexture())
        {
            m_fbo->bind();
            m_context->functions()->glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            m_context->functions()->glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            m_context->functions()->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            m_gObj->Draw();
            m_fbo->release();

            m_context->functions()->glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 12);
            m_context->functions()->glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_fbo->texture());
        }

        m_context->doneCurrent();
        m_mutex->unlock();
    }
}

#version 440

in vec2 TexCoords;
uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture[8];
uniform float alphas[8];
uniform int count;

void main()
{
    vec4 firstColor = texture2D(diffuseTexture[0], TexCoords);
    float firstAlpha = alphas[0];
    firstColor.a = firstAlpha;
    vec4 outputColor = firstColor;

    for(int i = 1; i < count; ++i)
    {
        vec4 nextColor = texture2D(diffuseTexture[i], TexCoords);
        float nextAlpha = alphas[i];
        float combinedAlpha = firstAlpha + (nextAlpha * (1.0 - firstAlpha));
        outputColor = vec4((firstColor.rgb * firstAlpha) + (nextColor.rgb * nextAlpha * (1.0 - firstAlpha)), combinedAlpha);
        firstColor = outputColor;
        firstAlpha = combinedAlpha;
    }

    gl_FragColor = outputColor;
}
```

And this is my main Gui thread shader set up

```
void OnscreenGraphicsObject::BindToDraw()
{
    if (!m_program)
        return;
    m_program->bind();

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0 + 12);
    m_program->setUniformValue("onscreenTexture", 12);
    m_vao.bind();
}

#version 440

in vec2 TexCoords;
uniform sampler2D onscreenTexture;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(onscreenTexture, TexCoords);
}
```

I'm certain it's something dumb I've overlooked but I'm beating my head against the wall at this point. I've looked at all the documentation and it just seems like the shared contexts should make this FBO texture available across threads

Comment: When you say *"This is done with a secondary context "*, do you mean that you have 2 [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) and the contexts are shared?

Comment: And if the answer to what @Rabbid76 askied is "yes": How do you syncrhonize GL between the threads? Just when the draw call returns in the second thread does not mean that the GPU has finsished the draw - it most likely hasn't even started.

Comment: yes they are shared. And i think @derhass question is leading into using glSyncObjects? Is that correct? I started reading about them shortly after posting this and think that may be where i'm losing it.

Comment: yes, GL sync objects  are definitively a good means for such a synchronization. However, as a quick&dirty test you can try adding a `glFinish` after the last draw call  in the second thread and only use the texture after that has returned.